# How to move an object on a canvas continuously in one direction for as long as the mouse button is down?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom

I have a red circle with a blue circle circling around it. I am trying to move the red circle in the direction of the blue circle when the mouse button is pressed.

But it currently only moves once.

I would like to have it moving continually while I press the mouse button, so that it keeps moving towards the direction of where the blue circle happens to be, keeping the blue circle ahead of it (and not circling) for as long as the mouse button is down.

Here is my code. Click the mouse button to see the reaction of the red circle:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    X += positionX;
    Y += positionY;
})
function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX + X, positionY + Y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    positionX = 35 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY = 35 * Math.cos(angle);
    angle += 0.1;
    ctx.fill();   
}
function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}
animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continually have the red circle move towards the blue one, for as long as the mouse button is down, then you need to maintain the state of the mouse button. You can do that by keeping a global flag updated with a handler for the `mousedown` and the `mouseup` event.

Then move the code that updates `X` and `Y` into the animation loop: make that update when the flag is true (when the mouse button is down). On the other hand, only update the angle (for the blue circle) when the mouse button is *not* down:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;
let mouseButtonDown = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseButtonDown = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseButtonDown = false);

function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX + X, positionY + Y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    positionX = 35 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY = 35 * Math.cos(angle);
    ctx.fill();   
}
function animate(){
    if (mouseButtonDown) {
        X += positionX / 10;
        Y += positionY / 10;
    } else {
        angle += 0.1;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}
animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but after mousepress the blue circle is not stopping which is making the red circle to not move a straight line in the direction of blue circle at the time of press. @trincot

Comment: OK, I didn't get that requirement from your question. I will update my answer....

Comment: Updated with this requirement.